# "gcs" returns nothing in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

After I restarted my PC and then re-opened a .m script I was working on, that for some reason broke it. `gcs` for some reason returns `0×0 empty char array` when it's supposed to return the pathname of the current system.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the `gcs` [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/gcs.html)? It explicit states:

> gcs returns the path name of the current system. The current system is
>   one of these:
>
> - During editing, the system or subsystem most recently clicked or that
>     contains the block most recently clicked
> - During simulation of a system that contains an S-Function block, the
>     system or subsystem containing the S-Function block currently being
>     evaluated
> - During callbacks, the system containing any block whose callback
>     routine is being executed
> - During evaluation of MaskInitialization, the system containing the
>     block whose mask is being evaluated
> - The system most recently loaded into memory with load_system; only the
>     first use of load_system makes the model the current system

If you just restarted your pc and re-open your m script, nothing has been loaded yet. After you open MATLAB/Simulink and [load a project](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/load_system.html), then `gcs` will return the path for the current system.